Can we use "some" to replace "any" in "...and does not represent any Amazon employees despite any claims..."
From Teamsters union launching strike against Amazon in NYC, across country

But an Amazon spokesperson says the Teamsters are misleading the
public and does not represent any Amazon employees despite any claims,
and that, quote, "The truth is that the Teamsters have actively
threatened, intimidated, and attempted to coerce Amazon employees and
third-party drivers to join them, which is illegal and is the subject
of multiple pending unfair labor practice charges against the union."

Can we use "some" to replace "any"? Is it becasue there is a preceding 'does not'?

The text is very badly written. What it should say is: ...the Teamsters are misleading the public and do not represent any Amazon employees despite any claims to the contrary... You could in principle replace any there with some, but that would slightly change the meaning - any allows for the possibility (even implies) that maybe no Amazon employees claim / agree that the Teamsters do in fact represent them, but some definitely rules out the possibility of there being none at all (at least two employees must say the Teamsters represent them).

@FumbleFingers Please stop answering in comments. First of all, this is not a written text, it is a journalist reporting orally on a situation. Secondly, why replace what is perfectly fine? "an Amazon spokesperson says the Teamsters are misleading the public and [it] does not represent any Amazon employees despite any claims. But a double subject is not needed.

No. That would imply that a portion of the claims (that the union represents workers) are true. Amazon is saying that all such claims are false.

No. Here, despite some claims to the contrary would typically be interpreted to mean “despite the fact that there do exist claims to the contrary,” whereas the clear intent of the Amazon spokesperson is “no matter what claims anyone might make.” So the only correct way to phrase it is despite any claims to the contrary.
By the way, a scrap of legal jargon that conveys pretty much the same meaning as any here is any and all.

Exactly. But I can see how it might be confusing for a learner to see ...any Amazon employees despite any claims..., because we certainly wouldn't want to replace the first any with any and all. That would imply there might not even be any Amazon employees, which is clearly nonsense. But as you say, lawyers would probably go for any and all claims in such contexts, just to be on the safe side and cover all possibilities.

Couldn't 'any' be replaced by 'all'?

@PhilFreedenberg, it depends (as always!) on context, and on what is meant. Despite all claims to the contrary strongly implies that there do exist such claims, and perhaps many, whereas despite any claims to the contrary allows the possibility that no such claims exist.

You use some for positive statements, and any for negative statements, where it means none:

I think there are some cookies in the kitchen
I don't think there are any cookies in the kitchen

In your sentence, does not has no effect on the meaning of the any that you highlighted: any in this context simply means all. It would be grammatically correct to replace it by some, but this would change the meaning.
Does not affects the meaning the earlier any in the sentence, making it mean none:

But an Amazon spokesperson says the Teamsters are misleading the
public and does not represent any Amazon employees despite any claims,
and that, quote, "The truth is that the Teamsters have actively
threatened, intimidated, and attempted to coerce Amazon employees and
third-party drivers to join them, which is illegal and is the subject
of multiple pending unfair labor practice charges against the union."


The Teamsters [Labor Union] does not represent any Amazon employees despite any claims [to the contrary, stating or suggesting that it does].
To have said "despite some claims"  would mean that the speaker is acknowledging that there have indeed been such claims, whereas "despite any claims" is a "blanket" statement that merely addresses the possibility that there have been or may be such claims. No such claim, if there were to be one, would be true.

No, you can't use 'some' to replace 'any' and I suggest a more important… at least more useful… Question might be, why would you want to?
The Question is not about language but rather, the legal effect of language. Does that much work for you?
I suggest 'Some' might matter in general semantics but in law, you'd need to differentiate 'Some…' from 'Any…', most obviously by defining what, here, 'Some…' means to you.
Can you?

"at least more useful…Question might be, why would you want to?" Because the OP is learning/perfecting their English, and wants to understand? By the way, why the capital letter in "Question"? Is it a proper noun? Why would you capitalise it in the middle of a sentence? Twice no less. Even if you could, should you? What has the question got to do with legal effect? Can you share some examples where "some" is preferred in negative sentences? Too many questions? –
Mari-Lou A
Commented9 mins ago
